# How do I execute a system stored procedure from Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework-4

The following code is supposed to run the sys.sp_setapprole stored procedure in my database. It does not. As the code sits right now I'm getting a `System.InvalidOperationException` with the following inner exception `The FunctionImport 'sp_setapprole' could not be found in the container 'XXX'`.

Any thoughts how I can execute this stored procedure ?

```
partial void OnContextCreated()
{
    this.Connection.StateChange += (sender, args) =>
    {
        if (args.CurrentState == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
                var conn = (EntityConnection)sender;
                EntityCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = "XXX.sp_setapprole";  
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("rolename", "XXX");
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("password", "XXX");
                cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        }
    };


}
```

Update 1 - Using `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` causes an InvalidCastException, "`Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection' to type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection'.`"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/129c59fc-9ce5-45fe-ac35-e58714544787/):

Comment: You should not simply post a link as a solution, especially when the link is to an alternative method to call the procedure that is not using Entity Framework. An answer like Ladislav's below is correct.

Answer (score 4):

Use `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand`. Executing stored procedure from EF via `EntityCommand` requires [function import](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896231.aspx) and function import for system procedures is not supported at least be the designer because you don't see common system stored procedures in the wizard when updating your EDMX model from the database.